# How does a FTP server resume a download?

Tags: sockets, ftp, ftp-server

I've been reading about the FTP protocol, but I cannot find in the protocol commands this feature that allows you to resume a partial download I have heard about.

How does it work? is there any "range" protocol command that I cannot find?

Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Resume is implemented using the [REST](http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/1123/64.htm) command - see [RFC 3659](http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/rfc/rfc3659.txt)

Comment: Fantastic, I'm blind. Thanks a million.