# what decides ftp download and stream?

Tags: ftp

While trying to setup an streaming server with my raspberry pi, the instructions seem to contain just installing an ftp server.

This made me wonder, what decides whether a file stored in the ftp server to be downloaded or streamed?
In other words, is the choice of downloading or streaming dependent on the client side and not the server side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using FTP, streaming is implemented client side using the REST command (for Start Position), as explained at [How does a FTP server resume a download?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678119/how-does-a-ftp-server-resume-a-download) and (in more detail) at http://cr.yp.to/ftp/retr.html .

Your server therefore needs to allow the REST verb (most do by default). Throttling (flow control) is also managed client side.

**Long story**:

This mechanism is similar to the strategy used by HTTP too. Streaming, however, is a wide subject. and there are other approaches to streaming. Some protocols provide extra verbs to signal other events like changes of bandwidth/resolution to account for unstable connections (like videoconference / desktop share protocols). Some are more suitable for live broadcasting and others for buffered/stored video.

Nowadays, most Streaming Players like YouTube are web based and built on top of the HTTP protocol. Streaming is achieved using the HTTP RANGE Header and by dividing the media in chunks that can be retrieved separately, as explained in this magnific video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OqQk7kLuaK4 .